# Repeating regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl, repeat

I have a string such as this

```
word <gl>aaa</gl> word <gl>aaa-bbb=ccc</gl>
```

where, if there is one ore more words enclosed in   tags. In those instances where there are more than one words (which are usually separated by - or = and potentially other non-word characters), I'd like to make sure that the tags enclose each word individually so that the resulting string would be:

```
word <gl>aaa</gl> word <gl>aaa</gl>-<gl>bbb</gl>=<gl>ccc</gl>
```

So I'm trying to come up with a regex that would find any number of iterations of \W*?(\w+) and then enclose each word individually with the tags. And ideally I'd have this as a one-liner that I can execute from the command line with perl, like so:

```
perl -pe 's///g;' in out
```

This is how far I've gotten after a lot of trial and error and googling - I'm not a programmer :( ... :

```
/<gl>\W*?(\w+)\W*?((\w+)\W*?){0,10}<\/gl>/
```

It finds the first and last word (aaa and ccc). Now, how can I make it repeat the operation and find other words if present? And then how to get the replacement? Any hints on how to do this or where I can find further information would be much appreciated?

**EDIT:** 
This is part of a workflow that does some other transformations within a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

perl -pe '# 
  s/replace/me/g;  
  s/replace/me/g;  
  ' $1 > tmp

... some other commands ...
```

Comment: Are you trying to transform a whole XML file?  Then you should use a module.  Also, why a one-liner? It will be unwieldy, in multiple lines, merely compressing what would be a normal program.  Is there something specifically bad about having a script for it?

Comment: @zdim It's not a full XML file. It's stretches of text that will eventually be transformed into LaTeX code. So the <gl>  </gl> tags are actually arbitrary, they could be anything and will eventually turn into \ and {}. I've just used the xml format as it's easily to recognize and unique enough so it won't mess other things up in the file.

Comment: And no, it doesn't have to be a oneliner.  It's actually part of a workflow that executes perl within a shell script, so a perl script would probably also do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
s/(\w+)([\-=])(?=\w+)/$1<\/gl>$2<gl>/g;
```

The /g at the end is the repeat and stands for "global".  It will pick up matching at the end of the previous match and keep matching until it doesn't match anymore, so we have to be careful about where the match ends.  That's what the (?=...) is for.  It's a "followed by pattern" that tells the repeat to not include it as part of "where you left off" in the previous match.  That way, it picks up where it left off by re-matching the second "word".

The s/ at the beginning is a substitution, so the command would be something like:

```
cat in | perl -pne 's/(\w+)([\-=])(?=\w+)/$1<\/gl>$2<gl>/g;$_' > out
```

You need the $_ at the end because the result of the global substitution is the number of substitutions made.

This will only match one line.  If your pattern spans multiple lines, you'll need some fancier code.  It also assumes the XML is correct and that there are no words surrounding dashes or equals signs outside of  tags.  To account for this would necessitate an extra pattern match in a loop to pull out the values surrounded by gl tags so that you can do your substitution on just those portions, like:

```
my $e = $in;
while($in =~ /(.*?<gl>)(.*?)(?=<\/gl>)/g){
    my $p = $1;
    my $s = $2;
    print($p);
    $s =~ s/(\w+)([\-=])(?=\w+)/$1<\/gl>$2<gl>/g;
    print($s);
    $e = $';   # ' (stop markup highlighter)
}
print($e);
```

You'd have to write your own surrounding loop to read STDIN and put the lines read in into `$in`.  (You would also need to not use -p or -n flags to the perl interpreter since you're reading the input and printing the output manually.)  The while loop above however grabs everything inside the gl tags and then performs your substitution on just that content.  It prints everything occurring between the last match (or the beginning of the string) and before the current match (`$p`) and saves everything after in `$e` which gets printed after the last match outside the loop.

Comment: You can test it with `perl -e '$s="word <gl>aaa</gl> word <gl>aaa-bbb=ccc</gl>";print("$s\n");$s=~s/(\w+)([\-=])(?=\w+)/$1<\/gl>$2<gl>/g;print("$s\n")'`

Comment: This is perfect and sufficient for what I need.

Comment: This code breaks if you feed it data with extra hyphenated words that are *not* within a `<gl>`...`</gl>` block. Just try "`word <gl>aaa</gl> word extra-hyphenated-word <gl>aaa-bbb=ccc</gl>`". This assuming the `word`s in the input are some random words or word combinations - this won't be a problem if the only things in input apart from the `<gl>` blocks are literal `word`s.

Comment: Yes, @Silvar, it assumes proper input. I was aware of that when I suggested it, though I didn't mention it. I will add that as a caveat.

Comment: OK @Silvar, after the caveat, I added code to address the code breakage you uncovered.

Comment: I'm sure there are probably other ways to break the code that have to do with unexpected input (e.g. upper case gl tags, etc.).  Though the OP said he wanted to do this in the form of "`perl -pe 's///g;' in out`" and I don't think that a single pattern match can handle what you pointed out my code could not handle, so I'd be very impressed if you were able to come up with a single regular expression that will do the requested substitution and handle the issue you brought up.

Answer (score 2):

This needs a mini nested-parser and I'd recommend a script, as easier to maintain

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = q(word <gl>aaa</gl> word <gl>aaa-bbb=ccc</gl>);

my $tag_re = qr{(<[^>]+>) (.+?) (</[^>]+>)}x;   # / (stop markup highlighter)

$str =~ s{$tag_re}{
    my ($o, $t, $c) = ($1, $2, $3);  # open (tag), text, close (tag)
    $t =~ s/(\w+)/$o$1$c/g; 
    $t;
}ge;

say $str;
```

The regex gives us its built-in "parsing," where words that don't match the `$tag_re` are unchanged. Once the `$tag_re` is matched, it is processed as required inside the replacement side. The `/e` modifier makes the replacement side be evaluated as code.

One way to provide input for a script is via command-line arguments, available in `@ARGV` global array in the script. For the use indicated in the question's "Edit" replace the hardcoded

```
my $str = q(...);
```

with

```
my $str = shift @ARGV;  # first argument on the command line
```

and then use that script in your shell script as

```
#!/bin/sh
...
script.pl $1 > output_file
```

where `$1` is the shell variable as shown in the "Edit" to the question.

---

In a one-liner

```
echo "word <gl>aaa</gl> word <gl>aaa-bbb=ccc</gl>"  |
    perl -wpe'
        s{(<[^>]+>) (.+?) (</[^>]+>)}
         {($o,$t,$c)=($1,$2,$3);$t=~s/(\w+)/$o$1$c/g; $t}gex;
    '
```

what in your shell script becomes   `echo $1 | perl -wpe'...' > output_file`. Or you can change the code to read from `@ARGV` and drop the `-n` switch, and add a print

```
#!/bin/sh
...
perl -wE'$_=shift; ...; say' $1 > output_file
```

where `...` in one-liner indicate the same code as above, and `say` is now needed since we don't have the `-p` with which the `$_` is printed out once it's processed.

The [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) takes an element off of an array's front and returns it. Without an argument it does that to `@ARGV` when outside a subroutine, as here (inside a subroutine its default target is `@_`).

Comment: @jan Added the one-liner

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, this is great.  I'm sorry, I just accepted the other answer before your edit, as the one-liner was working fine in my workflow.

Comment: Although, I must admit (as a non-expert) your code looks more sophisticated.

Comment: @jan  That's perfectly fine, what you accept and all :)  Was just letting you know.  If you can explain how you actually want to pass the string to Perl in your shell script I can add a way to make the script use it.  Again, just as an additional resource for you.  (This code doesn't assume fixed strings for your tags so it must do more. While it can be simplified but I wanted to avoid advanced regex.)

Comment: Adding `s{(<[^>]+>) (.+?) (</[^>]+>)}
         {($o,$t,$c)=($1,$2,$3);$t=~s/(\w+)/$o$1$c/g; $t}gex;` to my shell script above (after the other regexes) does exactly what I need!  The data is passed on to the script from another program as the `$1` argument and then the output is produced within the script calling some other commands.

Comment: @jan I edited to also show a way to use a script in your use case